# What chemicals does airport security use as markers?

Tags: usa, airports, security, tsa

I recently travelled to the USA from Asia.
When I arrived in Detroit they marked my E-cigarette with a clear colorless liquid using a small paint brush used for water colors.

What chemical(s) do they use as markers?

Comment: As a related question what is the purpose of the marking?

Comment: @Phil: "marking" is to elicit a chemical reaction with compounds of explosives that most likely makes the clear liquid change color.

Comment: @Jonas, thanks.  I wasn't aware they did that with liquids too.  Whenever I've been checked it's been with the cloth in in the wand thing

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about science/chemicals - not a travel question.

Comment: @MarkMayo But the fact that something similar may be experienced by travellers makes it relevant right?

Answer (score 3):

They are known as taggants. I found [an article about them on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taggant).

Hope it helps.